# agm/core and angular/google-maps what are the differences between them for google maps

Tags: angular, google-maps, agm

In my Angular application I need to add `google map`. I came across two libraries, not sure which one to use

```
npm install @angular/google-maps
npm install @agm/core --save
```

Can anyone please let me know which one is latest and has easy to develop or both are same.

This type of map I want to develop

- Map without vertical and horizontal lines
- I should be able to change background color
- Countries should show cities when I zoom it
- I should be able to show circle on particular location

[image]

Answer (score 9):

| Library | Doc | npm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| @angular/google-maps | [link](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/google-maps/README.md) | [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/google-maps) |
| @agm/core | [link](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/) | [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@agm/core) |

`@agm/core` is an Angular adapter of Google Maps JavaScript Core API developed by [Sebastian Holstein](https://github.com/SebastianM) that is very popular in npm but is no longer maintained, the last update was in July 2020.

`@angular/google-maps` is developed by the official Angular team and the preferred choice as it has better support and maintenance.

**Important**: to use the Google Maps Javascript Core API in a prod environment you have to pay ([Google Maps Javascript API usage and billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing)).

If you don't need to use Google Maps specifically, you could consider an open-source alternative library like leaflet ([comparison](https://www.codementor.io/@victorgerardtemprano/google-maps-api-or-leaflet--what-s-best-for-your-project-faaev60vm))

| Library | Doc | npm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| leaflet | [link](https://leafletjs.com/) | [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet) |

Answer (score 4):

- @angular/google-maps - supported by angular team
- @agm/core - is supported by [Sebastian Holstein](https://github.com/SebastianM)

Which one to use depends on which feature set you need. I found my self @agm/core providing me more features but again it depends on what you need.